# Specify settings.json file deploying on remote meteor free service

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to specify a settings file running a remote deploy of a meteor app on their free service?

in other words how can I issue the remote equivalent of  "meteor run --settings settings.json" ?

thanks

Answer (score 18):

Try deploying using:

`meteor deploy XXX.meteor.com --settings settings.json`

...instead of simply `meteor deploy XXX.meteor.com`

> You can initialize settings by passing the --settings option [...] to `meteor run` or `meteor deploy`

cf [Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_settings)

Comment: I tried this but my server still crashed because it couldn't find a key that is defined in settings.json. Any thoughts as to why? (Running Meteor 1.2)

Comment: a key? what do you mean? a crypto key? a key-value?

Comment: A key as in key-value pair of the JSON.

Comment: ok. can you share the exact error message that made you think that a missing key was the cause of that problem please?

Comment: Just as an update, this did work for me on Meteor 1.2.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to deploy from the remote server where settings.json is not available then convert your JSON to the inline equivalent and export it to METEOR_SETTINGS environment variable.

For example running from the server:

```
export METEOR_SETTINGS='{your json}'
meteor deploy XXX.meteor.com
```

This way you can make use of CI services like Travis where you can set METEOR_SETTINGS as secret variable and run deployment script.

Comment: Using this answer, my server did not crash. Though I recommend doing ``export METEOR_SETTINGS=`cat settings.json` ``